# Where can I find the Visual Studio 2010 RTM release notes?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

**Question**

Where can I find a list of changes introduced to *Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RTM* that were added since *Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RC*?

In fact, I'm only interested in changes related to MS Test Manager 2010 and Coded UI Tests.

**Where I have looked so far**

I have

- searched the Internet,
- looked for a readme.txt in the installation folder,
- looked into the Visual Studio help (F1) and
- browsed the "[What's new in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063(v=VS.100).aspx)" section on MSDN.

No luck.

Found Scott Guthrie's blog post [Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4 Released](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/12/visual-studio-2010-and-net-4-released.aspx), but that's not exactly what I am looking for. It's not a changelog since VS2010RC.

I suppose there is no such file because they made too many changes to document and hand out to end users. But if there was, I'd be glad if someone could point me to it. Thanks.

Comment: What level of detail are you looking for? As I understand it, from what I've picked up on various blogs, the majority of the changes between RC and RTM are performance related.

Comment: Pretty detailed: what bugs have been fixed and what features added. Among others this problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsautotest/thread/c130484c-646d-49f8-9257-26c663e01b93

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose actually there are no interesting changes except improving performance and fixing some bugs that are major enough to accept risk of changes. I think so because they actively refuse any change requests in Microsoft Connect and in blogs saying that product is already designed, developed and tested and now they are working only on performance.